# Why the new header isn't iterating (always print the same header), not the next header

Tags: python, data-analysis

This is my code

```
def PhaseInterval(arrival_file, filter_file, header_file):
    # read the stations from the filter file
    with open(filter_file, 'r') as f:
        filter_stations = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]

    # read the new header from the header file
    with open(header_file, 'r') as f:
        new_header = f.readline().strip()

    with open(arrival_file, 'r') as f:
        data = f.readlines()
        for i, line in enumerate(data):
            if 'pha' in line and len(line.split()) > 8:
                station = line.split()[0]
                print(new_header)
                #print(station, line.split()[4], line.split()[5], line.split()[7])
            elif 'amp' not in line and len(line.split()) > 8 and 'Origin' not in line: 
                station = line.split()[0]
                if station in filter_stations:
                    print(station, line.split()[4], line.split()[5], line.split()[8])
```

`PhaseInterval('garut_arrivals.txt','name_of_station','event_format.csv')`

Here are the results

```
2018 1 15 19 40 39.8 -7.41306 107.71983 10.0 2.7 0.0 0.0 0.82 1
BBJI P 19:40:43.1 1.0
BBJI S 19:40:45.6 1.0
CNJI P 19:40:51.5 1.0
CNJI S 19:41:00.0 1.0
LEM P 19:40:51.3 1.0
LEM S 19:40:59.8 1.0
2018 1 15 19 40 39.8 -7.41306 107.71983 10.0 2.7 0.0 0.0 0.82 1
BBJI Pg 15:20:57.8 1.0
LEM P 15:21:01.0 1.0
CNJI P 15:21:03.6 1.0
JCJI P 15:21:05.5 1.0
2018 1 15 19 40 39.8 -7.41306 107.71983 10.0 2.7 0.0 0.0 0.82 1
BBJI P 22:33:45.9 1.0
BBJI S 22:33:49.9 1.0
LEM P 22:33:49.0 1.0
...
```

I want the header (2018 ...) are not printing the same header but print the next order of the header.

Here are the new_header:

```
2018 1 15 19 40 39.8 -7.41306 107.71983 10.0 2.7 0.0 0.0 0.82 1
2018 2 5 15 20 51.9 -7.21515 107.71812 12.0 2.7 0.0 0.0 0.65 2
2018 2 17 22 33 40.4 -7.25412 107.71104 10.0 2.9 0.0 0.0 0.53 3
2018 4 10 13 46 9.9 -7.23121 107.67741 10.0 2.4 0.0 0.0 0.64 4
2018 4 30 17 25 58.9 -7.18669 107.61525 10.0 2.4 0.0 0.0 0.68 5
2018 5 15 21 5 55.9 -7.20198 107.63742 10.0 1.8 0.0 0.0 0.47 6
...
```

Thank you for your attention

Answer (score 0):

`new_header` is assigned with the first line of the header file and won't magically change itself unless you assign to it something else.

To print each line of the header file only when a certain condition is met, you can use the file object as an iterator and simply call the `next` function on it to obtain the next line as needed:

```
with open(header_file, 'r') as header, open(arrival_file, 'r') as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if 'pha' in line and len(line.split()) > 8:
            station = line.split()[0]
            print(next(header), end='')
        elif ...:
```